# How to ignore server side validation?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to avoid server side validation in yii2. Is there any method to disable server side validation?

I gave `validateOnSubmit` as false in the `activeForm` but its not work.

Comment: Can you post more information? do you actually mean server side validation and not client side? $model->save(false) does not work?

Answer (score 4):

When you save your model, just pass false which means to skip validation.

```
$model->save(false);
```